# Cant add space separated inputs using for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

I am trying to add space separated inputs to hashmap using for loop but I got some problems

```
    int G = s.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < G; i++) {
        System.out.println("List girls qualities");     
        int j=1;
        String gir=s.next();
        String[] numbers = gir.split(" ");
        girlQualities=new HashMap<>();
        for (int x=0;x<numbers.length;x++)  
        {  
            int z=Integer.parseInt(numbers[x]);
            girlQualities.put(j,z); 
            j++;
        }
    }
```

When I used `nextLine()` its showing NumberFormatException but even now its not working. Please help me
My target is to add numbers in this way

```
    3 
1 2 5 6 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Java has a `Scanner` that is rather sophisticated to parse all kinds of input.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem does the code OP provided not imply they are using a Scanner called `s`?

Comment: didn't get you @gifpif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because the `Scanner#nextInt` method does not consume the last newline character of your input, and thus that newline is consumed in the next call to `Scanner#nextLine`

Try

```
        int G = s.nextInt();
        s= new Scanner(System.in);
```

And then try `nextLine()` Method

Refer the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Comment: kindly could you please explain why its happening. nextLine should return current line. I am little bit confused about the above scenario

Comment: Click the Refer link given at the end of answer for detailed expiation ..